# How to style contact form 7 file input buttons

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I can't seem to target the button for up loading a file within contact form 7. How can I target the choose file button so I can add a background-color etc. Oh I am also doing this is WordPress incase you need to know that. So in the backend it looks like this;

```
<label class="form_label"> Your Name<span>*</span>
[text* your-name]</label>

<label class="form_label"> Your Email<span>*</span>
[email* your-email]</label>

<label class="form_label">Tel
[tel tel]</label>

<label class="form_label">CV<span>*</span>
[file cv id:upload]</label>

<label class="form_label">Cover Letter
[textarea your-message]</label>

[submit "Send"]
```

My output html looks like below.

```html
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f47-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
  <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
  <form action="/Lester_Goddard_New/#wpcf7-f47-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div style="display: none;">
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="47" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f47-o1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" />
    </div>
    <p><label class="form_label"> Your Name<span>*</span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label></p>
    <p><label class="form_label"> Your Email<span>*</span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label></p>
    <p><label class="form_label">Tel<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel"><input type="tel" name="tel" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label></p>
    <p><label class="form_label">CV<span>*</span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap cv"><input type="file" name="cv" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label></p>
    <p><label class="form_label">Cover Letter<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span></label></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
    <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I already tried putting an id on it and it didn't work

Comment: I have tried this. I cannot target just the button. If you think it is possible can you please show me. Thanks

Comment: Yeah just the button. This is the problem I have been having. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot style the button of file upload like any button, instead you may use pseudo element to cover the button and apply style to it. You may try something like this. You can change the content and the style of the "new" button like you want :

```css
span.cv {
  position:relative;
}
span.cv:before {
  content:"Upload file";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  padding:5px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  width:130px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
span.cv>input {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f47-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
  <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
  <form action="/Lester_Goddard_New/#wpcf7-f47-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div style="display: none;">
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="47" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f47-o1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" />
    </div>
    <p><label class="form_label"> Your Name<span>*</span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label></p>
    <p><label class="form_label"> Your Email<span>*</span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label></p>
    <p><label class="form_label">Tel<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel"><input type="tel" name="tel" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label></p>
    <p><label class="form_label">CV<span>*</span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap cv"><input type="file" name="cv" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label></p>
    <p><label class="form_label">Cover Letter<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span></label></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
    <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `visibility: hidden` to `<input type="file">` in order to hide the original element behind, which may be wider than the overlaid button.

Answer (score 6):

I had to change `visibility:hidden;`
by  `opacity:0;`

according to https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html so to the button continues to work otherwise the click didn't prompt the browse.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, as this indeed correct. Accepted answer is actually wrong/bad without this added information as it stops the button from working.

Comment: @Hybridwebdev the accepted answer isn't wrong and we don't need to change visibility with opacity because we have the label that is getting the click event. Actually the solution provided in the link here is *bad* because it uses a div thus we still need the click event on an invisible input which is not the case of the accepted answer (PS: don't edit answer to change its meaning even if you think it's wrong. Comment or add a new answer). Even `display:none` will work with the accepted answer.

Comment: No. It doesn't work. I know this, as I came across this answer when I myself was looking to implement a styled file input. Your answer was wrong as the click event for the file input never fired. It was only when I changed it to opacity that it worked. I believe this is because if the input is hidden, click events do not pass through. I believe you did not test this thoroughly, or you'd see why it does not work. That you removed my edit just shows you're unable to accept criticism. Please do future readers a favor, swallow your pride and edit your answer to reflect the correct solution.